# How to graph mixed data series with total 500k points

Tags: web-applications, scripting, graph

I need to draw a graph of the response time of various requests into my webapp. I have parsed the access logs from my application to produce a data file in the following format:

```
DateTime,ResponseTime,RequestType
```

For example:

```
09/Nov/2010:21:00:00,0.002,EVENT
09/Nov/2010:21:00:01,0.040,ACTION
```

My data file has 500k lines with the different request types all mixed up. The lines are currently ordered by time.

What would be the best tool for drawing all 500k points on one graph with a line per request type, time along the X axis and response time along the Y axis?

Comment: Have you already determined that a line graph is the best way to represent this data - there are other options that may do so more usefully - eg scatter graphs with each request type in a different colour?

Comment: A scatter graph would also be acceptable, possibly with a trend line/curve through all the points? The graph style isn't as important as having a tool which can handle so many points and in a mixed up format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wrote a Java program to parse the data into fewer data points which I could then graph in Excel. The code is specific to my particular use case so I won't bother to paste it in here.